# Paypal PDT - SSL connect error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-pdt

I use this code to process Paypal payment data transfer (PDT):

```
$url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
$tx_token = $_GET['tx'];
$auth_token = "my_token";

$fields = array(
    'cmd' => '_notify-synch',
    'tx' => $tx_token,
    'at' => $auth_token,
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
$status   = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);

echo "status:   " . $status;
curl_close($ch);
```

And I'm getting:

```
Curl error: SSL connect error
status: 0
```

I tried to make the API in Postman with the same URL: www.sandbox.paypal.com with the same parameters (cmd, at, tx) and I got success response. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal has upgraded to TLS 1.2 for its sandbox API endpoints. You can find out more about the upgrade and when it will affect production at the [TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 Upgrade Microsite](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1914&expand=true&locale=en_US).

You will need OpenSSL to be 1.0.1c or higher and a recent version of libcurl.
As far as your specific code, you probably want to do the following:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); // CURL_SSLLVERSION_TLSv1_2 = 6`

Also, you probably should leave the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to be `2` to verify the SSL certificate for the endpoint.

You can find out more at the [PayPal TLS update repository](https://github.com/paypal/tls-update) for specific language environment requirements.

Comment: I added: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); // CURL_SSLLVERSION_TLSv1_2 = 6` and leaved the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to be 2. Now I don't receive Curl error but I receive: `status: 200` `string(5) "FAIL "` Thanks!!

Comment: I managed to get this fixed (I had an error with the tx). Your suggestion works!!! Thanks!!